# Google-sheets count-up feature

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I'm looking for a count up feature for google-sheets, so once the user fills in the date on column A2 then an automated countup timer starts in cell B2

Only scripts I find is countdown features

Comment: Welcome. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested on [ask].

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest having a listener event trigger on google script that when the cell is updated, there is a function (for loop) that counts down from whatever time you want and update the value of your cell

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  //Range here is what was changed.Use that to call a function that starts a timer
}
```